# spacing between rows in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting

I have a table here. But it does not look right. First thing is regarding the spacing between rows. I need to increase the spacing. Second thing is at row 25, the number somehow exceeds the column. Any idea how to fix that. I tried using `//` to bring it down, but it does not work.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|c|c|}
\hline
25 & $-2^2 \cdot 3^6 \cdot13^2\cdot103^2\cdot643355871684956977670141294665607837^2$ & $13\cdot103\cdot643355871684956977670141294665607837$ & -2 \\ 
 \hline
 26 & $2^2\cdot3^4\cdot30347^2\cdot49857737^2\cdot357534917849299^2 \cdot1706574816319801^2$ & $30347\cdot49857737\cdot357534917849299\cdot1706574816319801$ & 1 \\ 
 \hline
27 & $-2^2\cdot3^6\cdot659^2\cdot1543^2\cdot7901^2\cdot5808403^2\cdot158844137^2\cdot 1158342511^2 \cdot50827475227^2$ & $659\cdot1543\cdot7901\cdot 5808403\cdot 158844137\cdot 1158342511\cdot50827475227$ & -1 \\ 
\hline
28 & $2^2 \cdot3^4\cdot19^2 \cdot987143^2\cdot635616634615737191007756403110436513428793^2$ & $19\cdot 987143\cdot635616634615737191007756403110436513428793$ & 1 \\ 
\hline
 29 & $-2^2 \cdot3^6\cdot1073602478183^2 \cdot18489706532449215619546038681792311392837^2$ & $1073602478183\cdot 18489706532449215619546038681792311392837$ & 1 \\ 
 \hline
 30 & $3^4\cdot127^2\cdot6173^2\cdot80831^2\cdot224969^2\cdot3156697^2\cdot 5489411^2\cdot 60570921936790713413493767^2$ & $127\cdot 6173\cdot 80831\cdot 224969\cdot 3156697\cdot 5489411\cdot 60570921936790713413493767$ & 1 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabularx}\captionof{table}{$B_n=4w_n^2$} \label{table:Bn}
```

Answer (score 4):

To fix the first issue, you could insert (typographic) struts. One per line suffices.

To fix the second issue, you need to get a wider text block; I suggest you display the table in landscape mode, e.g., by using the `sidewaystable` environment of the `rotating` package. (One mustn't introduce a line break in numbers such as `635616634615737191007756403110436513428793`, right?!)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,rotating}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}} % "top" strut
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|L|L|c|}
\hline
25\Tstrut & 
$-2^2 \cdot 3^6 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 103^2 \cdot 643355871684956977670141294665607837^2$ & 
$13 \cdot 103 \cdot 643355871684956977670141294665607837$ & 
$-2$ \\ 
\hline
26\Tstrut & 
$2^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 30347^2 \cdot 49857737^2 \cdot 357534917849299^2 \cdot 1706574816319801^2$ & 
$30347 \cdot 49857737 \cdot 357534917849299 \cdot 1706574816319801$ & 
1 \\ 
\hline
27\Tstrut & 
$-2^2 \cdot 3^6 \cdot 659^2 \cdot 1543^2 \cdot 7901^2 \cdot 5808403^2 \cdot 158844137^2 \cdot 1158342511^2 \cdot 50827475227^2$ & $659 \cdot 1543 \cdot 7901 \cdot 5808403 \cdot 158844137 \cdot 1158342511 \cdot 50827475227$ & 
$-1$ \\ 
\hline
28\Tstrut & 
$2^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 987143^2 \cdot 635616634615737191007756403110436513428793^2$ & 
$19 \cdot 987143 \cdot 635616634615737191007756403110436513428793$ & 
1 \\ 
\hline
29\Tstrut & 
$-2^2 \cdot 3^6 \cdot 1073602478183^2 \cdot 18489706532449215619546038681792311392837^2$ & 
$1073602478183 \cdot 18489706532449215619546038681792311392837$ & 
1 \\ 
\hline
30\Tstrut & 
$3^4 \cdot 127^2 \cdot 6173^2 \cdot 80831^2 \cdot 224969^2 \cdot 3156697^2 \cdot 5489411^2 \cdot 60570921936790713413493767^2$ & 
$127 \cdot 6173 \cdot 80831 \cdot 224969 \cdot 3156697 \cdot 5489411 \cdot 60570921936790713413493767$ & 
1 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{$B_n=4w_n^2$} \label{table:Bn}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: I would like to encourage you to think about giving the table a more open and inviting look: To avoid creating a look of "lots of little prison cells", consider getting rid of all vertical bars and all interior horizontal bars. In their place, use the macros of the `booktabs` package to draw the remaining two horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,rotating,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}} % "top" strut
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % some more whitespace
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cLLr@{}}
\toprule
25  & 
$-2^2 \cdot 3^6 \cdot 13^2 \cdot 103^2 \cdot 643355871684956977670141294665607837^2$ & 
$13 \cdot 103 \cdot 643355871684956977670141294665607837$ & 
$-2$ \\ \addlinespace
26  & 
$2^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 30347^2 \cdot 49857737^2 \cdot 357534917849299^2 \cdot 1706574816319801^2$ & 
$30347 \cdot 49857737 \cdot 357534917849299 \cdot 1706574816319801$ & 
1 \\ \addlinespace
27  & 
$-2^2 \cdot 3^6 \cdot 659^2 \cdot 1543^2 \cdot 7901^2 \cdot 5808403^2 \cdot 158844137^2 \cdot 1158342511^2 \cdot 50827475227^2$ & $659 \cdot 1543 \cdot 7901 \cdot 5808403 \cdot 158844137 \cdot 1158342511 \cdot 50827475227$ & 
$-1$ \\ \addlinespace
28  & 
$2^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 987143^2 \cdot 635616634615737191007756403110436513428793^2$ & 
$19 \cdot 987143 \cdot 635616634615737191007756403110436513428793$ & 
1 \\ \addlinespace
29  & 
$-2^2 \cdot 3^6 \cdot 1073602478183^2 \cdot 18489706532449215619546038681792311392837^2$ & 
$1073602478183 \cdot 18489706532449215619546038681792311392837$ & 
1 \\ \addlinespace
30  & 
$3^4 \cdot 127^2 \cdot 6173^2 \cdot 80831^2 \cdot 224969^2 \cdot 3156697^2 \cdot 5489411^2 \cdot 60570921936790713413493767^2$ & 
$127 \cdot 6173 \cdot 80831 \cdot 224969 \cdot 3156697 \cdot 5489411 \cdot 60570921936790713413493767$ & 
1 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{$B_n=4w_n^2$} \label{table:Bn}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With (good old) package `mdwtab` you can easily obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mdwtab,tabularx}
    \usepackage{rotating}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash$}X<{$}|}Mr|}
    \hlx{hvv}
25  &   -2^2 \cdot 3^6 \cdot13^2\cdot103^2\cdot643355871684956977670141294665607837^2
        &   13\cdot103\cdot643355871684956977670141294665607837
            &   -2  \\
    \hlx{vvhvv}
26  &   2^2\cdot3^4\cdot30347^2\cdot49857737^2\cdot357534917849299^2 \cdot1706574816319801^2
        &   30347\cdot49857737\cdot357534917849299\cdot1706574816319801
            &   1   \\
    \hlx{vvhvv}
27  &   -2^2\cdot3^6\cdot659^2\cdot1543^2\cdot7901^2\cdot5808403^2\cdot158844137^2
                    \cdot 1158342511^2 \cdot50827475227^2
        &   659\cdot1543\cdot7901\cdot 5808403\cdot 158844137\cdot 1158342511\cdot50827475227
            &   -1  \\
    \hlx{vvhvv}
28  &   2^2 \cdot3^4\cdot19^2 \cdot987143^2\cdot635616634615737191007756403110436513428793^2
        &   19\cdot 987143\cdot635616634615737191007756403110436513428793
            &   1   \\
    \hlx{vvhvv}
29  &   -2^2 \cdot3^6\cdot1073602478183^2 \cdot18489706532449215619546038681792311392837^2
        &   1073602478183\cdot 18489706532449215619546038681792311392837
            &   1 \\
    \hlx{vvhvv}
30  &   3^4\cdot127^2\cdot6173^2\cdot80831^2\cdot224969^2\cdot3156697^2
                    \cdot 5489411^2\cdot 60570921936790713413493767^2
        &   127\cdot 6173\cdot 80831\cdot 224969\cdot 3156697\cdot 5489411
                    \cdot 60570921936790713413493767
            &   1   \\
    \hlx{vh}
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{$B_n=4w_n^2$}
\label{table:Bn}
    \end{sidewaystable}
    \end{document}
```

Note: package `mdwtab` is not compatible with package `colortbl`, so tables set by this can't be colored.

With addition of the `siunitx` package you can enclose all numbers with 4 or more digits in `\num{...}`. This will make them easier to read:

[image]